# Tridion CoreService create component missing metadata

Tags: metadata, tridion

**i got exception = {"Unable to find uuid:5708986b-390f-4728-b0c7-b49bd3d8f407:Metadata."}**

```cs
schemaId = UpdatePubId(schemaId, containerId);
SchemaData schemaData = (SchemaData)client.Read(schemaId, null);
string xml = string.Format("<{0} xmlns=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>", schemaData.RootElementName, schemaData.NamespaceUri, fields);

ComponentData componentData = new ComponentData
{
    Content = xml,
    ComponentType = ComponentType.Normal,
    Title = title,
    Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = schemaId },
    LocationInfo = new LocationInfo { OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItemData { IdRef = containerId } },
    Id = "tcm:0-0-0", 
    MetadataSchema = schemaData.MetadataSchema,
    Metadata = schemaData.Metadata
};

try
{
    componentData = client.Save(componentData, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
    componentData = client.CheckIn(componentData.Id, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
    message.Set("Component", title + ", successfully");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    message.Set("Component", exception.Message);
}
```

thanks Tridion experts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the correct path, but the error indicates that you have not provided the Metadata fields for the component that you are trying to create.

This line is incorrect:

```csharp
Metadata = schemaData.Metadata
```

It should pretty much, like that one where you create the content fields:

```csharp
Metadata = String.Format("<Metadata xmlns=\"{0}\">{1}</Metadata>",schemaData.NamespaceUri, "YOUR METADATA XML")
```

Comment: yes thanks Puntero this is correct, how to retrive Metadata from schema thanks again :)

Comment: i am getting another error The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011:deltaData. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData. Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 1, position 109.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: Check the strings that you are using to create the Metadata and Content fields, you are missing a ">" somewhere ;)

Comment: i should do xhtml vaidation before creating component :)

Comment: See sample here using Tidy.NET: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/06/importing-content-into-tridion.html